# versioning of records in dynamodb when used batchWrite

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I was using mapper.batchWrite() operation to save multiple records, but i observed that the way i was using versioning for save with `@DynamoDBVersionAttribute(attributeName = "Version")` isn't working with the batchWrite. In save() method the version is being intialized which is not the case with batchWrite.
And if there is a better practice to use versioning do let me know.

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

"No version checks are performed," for BatchWrite API

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/AbstractDynamoDBMapper.html#batchWrite-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-